# Iterator arraylist java

Tags: java

Tengo una duda en este caso y es porque al recorrer este arraylist y filtrarlo con un if para que solo me muestre los datos de la persona mayor a la edad que pongo como condicion..en vez de mostrarme tres personas, unicamente me muestra la persona del medio que cumple esta condicion.
Adjunto codigo

```
class empleados{

    private String nombre;
    private int edad;

    public empleados(String nombre, int edad) {
        setNombre(nombre);
        setEdad(edad);
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){        

        return "El nombre es " + nombre + " y la edad es " + edad;
    }
}

public class holass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<empleados> tiago = new ArrayList<empleados>();

        tiago.add(new empleados("Tiago", 20));
        tiago.add(new empleados("Matias", 50));
        tiago.add(new empleados("Roberto", 80)); 
        tiago.add(new empleados("Veronica", 51));

        //System.out.println(tiago.size());

        /*for(empleados e:tiago){

            if(e.getEdad() > 45){

                 System.out.println(e.toString());    

            }   

        }*/

        Iterator <empleados> iterador = tiago.iterator();

        while(iterador.hasNext()){

            if(iterador.next().getEdad() > 45){

                System.out.println(iterador.next().toString());   


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Iterator` es un *mecanismo* que va recorriendo la lista en orden y su método `next` (siguiente en español) te va devolviendo el siguiente elemento de la lista cada vez que lo llamas.

Entonces, cuando un empleado cumple la condición en el `if`, dentro imprimes el nombre del siguiente empleado, que puede que cumpla o no la condición. Debes retener la referencia al empleado que te va devolviendo el *iterador*.

Convierte el 'iterator.next()' en un objeto empeleado como:

```
empleado e = iterator.next();
```

Entonces quedaría:

```
Iterator <empleados> iterador = tiago.iterator();
while(iterador.hasNext()){
    empleados e = iterador.next();
    if(e.getEdad() > 45){
         System.out.println(e.toString());   
    }  
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvio. saludos

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero quedaría mejor si le explicases *por qué* funciona. Hazlo y te llevarás mi voto.

Comment: me lo podrias explicar tu david por favor?

Comment: @Tiago Viezzoli `iterator.next()` te devuelve el empleado al que está apuntando actualmente **y avanza una posición en la lista**. En tu caso hacías `iterator.next()` dos veces, al comparar la edad y al imprimir, es decir: **Estabas avanzando, sin saberlo, de dos en dos por cada pasada a la lista**

Comment: Muchas gracias david. saludos